# How to reset pgAdmin4 GUI?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, then pgAdmin4 v1.1 (on Windows 10 Pro x64) error. Then, I tried re-install, but error still exist:

[image]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like a web-page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> for reset zoom level.

Answer (score 90):

### RESET Layout :

1.The pgAdmin menu bar displays the following selections: *File, Object, Tools*, and Help.*

Use the **File** menu to access the following options:

> File -> Reset  Layout

OR

2. Open the browser console and run following :-

> pgAdmin.Settings.show()

This should pop up dialog: *"Are you sure you want to reset the current layout?* ..."

Comment: browser console, what is?

Answer (score 34):

I had this error too. The menu item "Reset Layout" was not visible. Actually NO menu item was visible, so I dug up the actual method that is triggered by the "Reset Layout".

To fix, do this:

- Open the browser console
- Paste this JavaScrips code: `pgAdmin.Settings.show()`
- This should pop up dialog: "Are you sure you want to reset the current layout? ..."

Comment: browser console ,what is and how open it

Answer (score 12):

Neither of the mentioned methods worked for me to reset the pgAdmin layout. Finally, what helped, was to delete the `..\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\` directory and install again.

Comment: This worked for me when my pgAdmin screen was essentially empty and the menu's didn't work, so couldn't use any of the other methods.

Comment: Thanks, @Codigo for your solution. It's saved my time & life as well.

Comment: Thank you, this works in version pgAdmin v7 for "Please select an object in the tree view" screen error.

Comment: No need to install, just deleted this file "pgadmin4.db" in ..AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

go to file option and select reset layout.
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgadmin_menu_bar.html

Answer (score 3):

For the pgAdmin desktop app, I deleted the `.pgadmin` (hidden) folder from my Home Directory on my Unix machine. Using the command:

```sh
rm -rf ~/.pgadmin
```

But be aware as it will delete all your saved connections too.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom in: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Zoom out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

..\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\runtime_config.json

change prop "zoomLevel": 1,

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem where none of the menus worked, so I couldn't use the reset option, but I was able to close pgadmin and open it again which gave me access to the file menu and reset layout.

Answer (score -2):

```
rm -rf ~/.pgadmin
```

It's work. to reset layout for mac.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).