# Unable to reset layout - pgadmin (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin-4

[image]

I am unable to reset layout in pgadmin, attaching screenshot. As you can see the typical option such as file, tools etc are not available. I've tried reinstall pgadmin, but apparently settings are somewhere in cache, because it did not help. Could you please have a look and advise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset pgAdmin4 GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777126/how-to-reset-pgadmin4-gui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After program upgrade everything came back to normal :)